# how to pass json request through websocket sampler in jmeter?

Tags: testing, websocket, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwxCc.png)I need to perform websocket testing using jmeter tool. I need to know that how can i pass the json request using websocket sampler in jmeter?
Is it possible to use csv data set to pass multiple orders using websocket sampler in jmeter?

Comment: what type of server side do you integrate with? which messaging protocol does it use (e.g. Stomp)? Can you show example of websocket communication (e.g. Java code, or capture from some tool like Chrome Network tab)

Comment: Its a websocket server. and the protocol we are using is ws. we are using jmeter tool for this. i have attached the screenshot aswell. please check and let me know.

Comment: @KirilS.  
 
Its a websocket server. and the protocol we are using is ws. we are using jmeter tool for this. i have attached the screenshot aswell. please check and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this plugin:

- https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/overview

Which you can install with jmeter-plugins download manager:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/

You can then use JMeter [CSV Data Set](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to get data from a CSV and pass it in body of Websocket

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going for the following test elements combination:

1. [Directory Listing Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DirectoryListing/) plugin to read all files under a specified path into a JMeter Variable, i.e. `filename`
2. [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function to read file contents and send it along with the request like `${__FileToString(${filename},,)}`

   [image: JMeter Directory Listing Config]

You can install Directory Listing Config plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager).

Comment: Can i not use this option "send parameters with the request"? Why are we going with request data?